# "android_asset/www/" missing from file paths when building without livereload

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic app (ionic v1.7.13, cordova v5.4.1). When I run

```
ionic run android -l
```

everything works fine, all my project files are properly loaded.
The problem arises when I try to run without livereload, specifically because livereload causes issues when accessing device files.

```
ionic run android
```

When I run this command I see only the html file rendered, and in the dev tools I see

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///lib/ionic/css/ionic.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///css/style.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///cordova.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///js/app.js
...
```

I can go through and add "android_asset/www/" to those routes and it works... but I think I must be missing something.

I'm looking for any guidance in others who have had this issue. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

turns out that trying to include html5location's in angular that it breaks the routes.

by removing `<base href="/">` from my index.html file I fixed all the relative routes and my problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.

Comment: same for me: Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same as Lucas's answer but

```
<base href="/" />
```

is changed to

```
<base href="." />
```

Comment: this works for me when running an ionic angular blank template on android@6: `ionic start myapp blank --type=angular` `ionic cordova platform add android@6 --confirm` `ionic cordova build android`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `config.xml`

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<access origin="*"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a solution for your exact problem, but this worked for me when i was receiving the same errors while running my react typescript app on cordova:

```
package.json
{
    ...
    "homepage": ".",
    ...
}
```