# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ionic error

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I have install whitelist plugin and in config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

but

i am getting error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///lib/ion-autocomplete/dist/ion-autocomplete.css Failed to load   resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///css/ionic.app.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///cordova.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///lib/moment/moment.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///lib/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/js/angular-bootstrap-calendar-tpls.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///lib/x2js/xml2json.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///lib/ionic-ajax-interceptor/dist/ionic-ajax-interceptor.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

It works fine when i test in browser but on testing on mobile device i am getting error above.

I have gone through all the solution available but can fix it at the moment

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding all of these

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<access origin="*"/>
```

EDIT:

To your `config.xml` file

Comment: Yeah this was answered 3 years ago, I doubt it's still relevant

Answer (score 4):

i was facing the same error and i fixed it by doing these 2 simple steps

1. `ionic cordova platform remove android`
2. `ionic cordova platform add android`

and after this just run the command `ionic cordova run android` and its work like a charm

Comment: This should be accepted answer !!!

Answer (score 2):

See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202759/android-asset-www-missing-from-file-paths-when-building-without-livereload).

remove `<base href="/">` from your index.html

Comment: That's a bad idea: deviceready will be not fire 'cause plugins are in an inconsistent state.

Comment: this fix made the ionicons not working, any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am getting same error,In my case my IP address was wrong.Check your if you are using IP address in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I only changed in index.html

```
<base href="/" />
```

to

```
<base href="." />
```