# What is the location for images in Ionic2?

Tags: ionic2

I am working with the latest version of Ionic2 (2.0.0 final! ) , and I am facing issue with the location of my images in the app.

My images location is:

> src\assets\img\

And in my html pages I am using the img tag like that:

```
<img src="img/do.png"/>
```

The images are loaded just fine when I'm running **ionic serve**.

But when I'm running "ionic run android"
The images are not loaded and I am getting the error :

> **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**
>
> file:///android_asset/www/img/do.png

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449936/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-file-not-found-ionic-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is located in `src\assets\img\do.png` then in your html code you need to use this path: `<img src="assets/img/do.png"/>`