# Geolocation is not working in Ionic 4 Android

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, android-emulator, ionic-native, ionic4

To get the current location in Android device, I used Ionic 4 [Geolocation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/) plugin and followed the steps given in the documentation. On running the Ionic CLI command ionic cordova run android --l --c, it launches the Application and prompts the location permission dialog. But it throws an error like `getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin.`

```
{
   PositionErrorcode: 1message: "Only secure origins are allowed ."__proto__: PositionError
   home.page.ts:37Error getting location PositionError
}
```

Also after reading the blogs and threads in forum, I just used the cli command `ionic cordova run android` (without reload). In that case app did not load since the sources were not loaded properly.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///polyfills.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///styles.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///cordova.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///vendor.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///main.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///assets/icon/favicon.png Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I also tried setting gps location in emulator using emulator extended control. Tried in real device and it also has such issues.

Answer (score 0):

In two sections, I will try to help, I was having the same two problems, I explain how I managed to "*fix*" them, perhaps it works for you too.

(1) Regarding this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///polyfills.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///styles.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///cordova.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///vendor.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///main.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///assets/icon/favicon.png Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Honestly, I am not sure what exactly is causing this, I am still investigating the root cause, as  I had this problem, in case it back.  Strangely, I had this problem with Android but not with iOS platform. What I have done to get this fixed was erase all the plugins and get them installed again:

```
// Inside your app's folder
$ rm -rf plugins 
// Just in case (I didn't do it, but who knows!) remove and add the platform again
$ ionic cordova platform remove android
$ ionic cordova platform add android
```

After that these errors went away.

(2) Regarding the Geolocation

Yes, that's true, I read the documentation about the HTTP/HTTPs and I also have the warning when using through the browsers. 
I was not getting the Geolocation working on the Devices (iOS and Android), it simply did not get any signal of life after writing the code exactly the Ionic's documentation was saying to. I thought it was because of the problem that Geolocation (HTTP/HTTPs) on [Chrome 50](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only).

So, I figured out that on the devices (Android and iOS) the Geolocation was working ok, **IF** you get them started after the Platform is ready (or use the Timeout parameter, as an alternative).
The code that made the devices getting the user's location was this:

```
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((loc) => {
              userLatitude  = loc.coords.latitude;
              userLongitude = loc.coords.longitude;
              map.flyTo({userLatitude:userLongitude}, MAX_ZOOM - 2, ZOOM_PAN_OPTIONS);
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.utils.error('Error getting location: ' + error.message);
        }); 
   };
```

I didn't test, but other alternative could be the use of the `Timeout` parameter on the method:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ timeout: 30000 }).then((loc) => { ...
```

I think that are many variables, regarding all the context, that could make this working or not. In my case, it happens this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
              this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
                console.log(resp);
                // resp.coords.latitude
                // resp.coords.longitude
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error getting location', error);
            });
```

my problem had been calling *twice*. 
**When you call repeatedly, the results may not come.
Make sure to call the function once.**

Answer (score -1):

Accessing the user's location is deprecated with unsecure (HTTP) context. 
See https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features.

It’s only a problem when using live reload.

This will work     `ionic cordova build android`

Comment: It didn't worked. As mentioned in my question, if I execute the command ionic cordova run android / ionic cordova build android, it throws error with title Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. This particular issue is not only for this project. After upgrading to Ionic 4, I am facing this for all projects. The same works if I add reload option. Thanks.

Comment: Try these two links, it might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202759/android-asset-www-missing-from-file-paths-when-building-without-livereload and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449936/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-file-not-found-ionic-error

Comment: That did not help. Removing <base href=""> from index.html gives me an error "Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document". Changing config as directed in the link did not did any change in the result.